# SQL Pivot Table

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table like this;

```
var1    var2    var3    cats

a      b       b       cat1
        b       b       cat1
a                      cat2
a      a       a       cat3
a      a       a       cat2
```

and want to get pivot table. I want to count a and b with the category of vars and cats.I am an excel user. I've looked other samples but could not solve this... thanks for help

```
vars    cats    a   b

var1    cat1    1   
var1    cat2    2   
var1    cat3    1   
var2    cat1        2
var2    cat2    1   
var2    cat3    1   
var3    cat1        2
var3    cat2    1   
var3    cat3    1
```

Comment: Are you in SQL or are you in Excel. If SQL, what SQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Sql Server 2005 yuo can make use of the [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        var1 VARCHAR(10),
        var2 VARCHAR(10),
        var3 VARCHAR(10),
        cats VARCHAR(10)
)


INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'a','b','b','cat1'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT null,'b','b','cat1'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'a',null,null,'cat2'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'a','a','a','cat3'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'a','a','a','cat2'

SELECT  MyVars,
        cats,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Vars = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) A,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Vars = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) B
FROM    (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  cats,
                                var1,
                                var2,
                                var3
                        FROM    @Table
                    )p
            UNPIVOT (Vars FOR MyVars IN (var1, var2,var3)) AS up
        ) sub
GROUP BY MyVars,
        cats
ORDER BY 1, 2
```